# Access Swift Class for Transition between Objective C ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, transition

I would like to use some Swift code that resides in a swift file for a custom transition between two view controllers written in Objective-C.

There is a bridging header in the project and I have had no problem going between Obj-C and Swift previously.  SO I'm wondering if there might be anything specific to the Transitioning code that makes it more difficult--or if I'm just missing one or more steps somewhere.

Basically, I do the following.

In .m file of Obj-class include statement

```
#import myProject-Swift.h
```

In .h file of Obj-class, include forward statement to Swift class

```
@class my file.Swift;
```

In Swift file, I have made it a subclass of NSObject although this was not necessary to the transition when I was doing it all in Swift.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
@objc class customTransition: NSObject {

}
```

In the Obj-class, I adopt the protocol:

```
<UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>
```

I set the delegate in ViewDIdLoad of the Obj-C file as follows:

```
self.transitioningDelegate = self;
```

Finally, I call the segue from the View Controller 1 (Obj-C) through a segue in Storyboard. Specifically, I have an action method:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showVC" sender:self];
```

But nothing happens and the code in the Swift class is never called.

**Edit**

Tn contrast, the code works perfectly called from an Objective C file when the destinationVC is a Swift View Controller using launch code of:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *myNav= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNav"];//this is a navbarcontroller
    [self presentViewController:myNav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Possibly, the presence of the Nav in storyboard in that case is the difference.  Do I have to have a separate navigation controller for the transition to work.

Comment: `myNav.transitioningDelegate = self` is what you're missing..

Comment: In destination Obj-c view controller?

Comment: I think my question may have been confusing so I edited it.  The code at the end that mentions myNav is from working code elsewhere in the app where the destination VC is in Swift.  Do I always need to have a dedicated nav for the destination VC to get the transition to work?